# Iterate through rows in data frame with n rows and n columns and count the frequency of combinations 1:n

Tags: python, pandas, collections, combinations, python-itertools

Iterate through rows in data frame with `n` rows and 6 columns and count the frequency of combinations `1:n` within each row.

Non working template code:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from collections import Counter

# create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [2, 10, 18, 31, 41],
   [12, 27, 28, 39, 42]
])

def get_combinations(row)
  all_combinations[]
  for i in range(1, len(df)+1):
    result = list(itertools.combinations(df, i))
    return all_combinations

# get all posssible combinations of values in a row
all_rows = df.apply(get_combinations, 1).values
all_rows_flatten = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_rows))

# use Counter to count how many there are of each combination
count_combinations = Counter(all_rows_flatten)
print(all_combinations["count_combinations"])
```

Comment: Can you clarify the logic and provide the expected output? Make sure your input is meaningful.

Comment: Hi Mozway, the the output should be a concatenated list of all possible combinations of numbers within each row and their frequencies. So the first row combinations would be [2,10,18,31,41, (2,10), (2, 18), ...(2,10,18,31,41)] with their associated frequencies that they occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```py
import itertools
from collections import Counter

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 10, 18, 31, 41], [12, 27, 28, 39, 42], [12, 4, 18, 6, 41]])


def get_combinations(row):
    all_combs = [
        c for i in range(1, len(row) + 1) for c in itertools.combinations(row, i)
    ]
    return all_combs


df["all_combs"] = df.apply(get_combinations, axis=1)

print(df)

cnt = Counter(c for combs in df["all_combs"] for c in combs)
print(cnt)
```

Prints:

```
    0   1   2   3   4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            all_combs
0   2  10  18  31  41                  [(2,), (10,), (18,), (31,), (41,), (2, 10), (2, 18), (2, 31), (2, 41), (10, 18), (10, 31), (10, 41), (18, 31), (18, 41), (31, 41), (2, 10, 18), (2, 10, 31), (2, 10, 41), (2, 18, 31), (2, 18, 41), (2, 31, 41), (10, 18, 31), (10, 18, 41), (10, 31, 41), (18, 31, 41), (2, 10, 18, 31), (2, 10, 18, 41), (2, 10, 31, 41), (2, 18, 31, 41), (10, 18, 31, 41), (2, 10, 18, 31, 41)]
1  12  27  28  39  42  [(12,), (27,), (28,), (39,), (42,), (12, 27), (12, 28), (12, 39), (12, 42), (27, 28), (27, 39), (27, 42), (28, 39), (28, 42), (39, 42), (12, 27, 28), (12, 27, 39), (12, 27, 42), (12, 28, 39), (12, 28, 42), (12, 39, 42), (27, 28, 39), (27, 28, 42), (27, 39, 42), (28, 39, 42), (12, 27, 28, 39), (12, 27, 28, 42), (12, 27, 39, 42), (12, 28, 39, 42), (27, 28, 39, 42), (12, 27, 28, 39, 42)]
2  12   4  18   6  41                                  [(12,), (4,), (18,), (6,), (41,), (12, 4), (12, 18), (12, 6), (12, 41), (4, 18), (4, 6), (4, 41), (18, 6), (18, 41), (6, 41), (12, 4, 18), (12, 4, 6), (12, 4, 41), (12, 18, 6), (12, 18, 41), (12, 6, 41), (4, 18, 6), (4, 18, 41), (4, 6, 41), (18, 6, 41), (12, 4, 18, 6), (12, 4, 18, 41), (12, 4, 6, 41), (12, 18, 6, 41), (4, 18, 6, 41), (12, 4, 18, 6, 41)]

Counter(
    {
        (18,): 2,
        (41,): 2,
        (18, 41): 2,
        (12,): 2,
        (2,): 1,
        (10,): 1,
        (31,): 1,
        (2, 10): 1,
        (2, 18): 1,
        (2, 31): 1,
        (2, 41): 1,
        (10, 18): 1,

...
```

To convert `cnt` dict to a dataframe:

```py
df_cnt = pd.DataFrame({"comb": cnt.keys(), "counts": cnt.values()})
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I convert cnt into a dataframe?

Comment: that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data only has unique combinations, so I changed it a bit.

Using a generator would be more memory efficient than computing all combinations in one go and iterating over the values only once will be way more CPU efficient (chaining built-in functions like flatten, counter, etc. will do multiple passes over the data).

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [2, 10, 18, 31, 41],
    [12, 27, 28, 39, 42],
    [12,4,18,6,41]
])

def combination_generator(values):
    for i in range(1, len(values)+1):
        for c in itertools.combinations(values, i):
            yield tuple(sorted(c))


combination_count=defaultdict(lambda:0)
df_dict = df.to_dict()
for row in df_dict:
    for c in combination_generator(df_dict[row].values()):
        combination_count[c]+=1

for c in combination_count:
    print(f'{c} : {combination_count[c]}')
```

Comment: Hi, sorry OM220, I should have clarified that I was looking for the unique combinations within each row. Will update the question.